# Cannot connect with Mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

When I try to launch the mongo shell  running the 'mongo' command in the terminal I get this error:

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2017-12-23T17:52:51.318+0100 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 
127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: 
Connection refused
2017-12-23T17:52:51.319+0100 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to 
server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

I cannot figur out what is the problem...

Comment: could you please share your code leading to the error ?

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to check whether mongo server is running on your local system by visiting below url in the browser.

```
http://127.0.0.1:27017
```

you can run the below command in case of ubuntu.

```
  $ sudo service mongod start
```

Then, Run:

```
$ mongo
```